# Error variance estimation with weights

Tags: variance, estimation, error, weights, survey-weights

I am using data which include a (sample-)weight for each observation, i.e. the data is from a survey that has weights to make the sample representative for the US-population.
I perform OLS to get some coefficients and I am trying to estimate the error variance,

```
sigma_hat^2 = RSS/(n-p)
```

now RSS is calculated using weights:

```
RSS = sum(w * (y-y_hat)^2)
```

The problem I am facing now is that RSS depends on the scale of the weights. Consequently sigma_hat^2 also depends on the scale of the weights.

Shall I use standardized weights (w=w/sum(1)) and then multiply RSS by (n/(n-p))?

How do I correctly estimate sigma_hat^2?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Why use OLS, instead of WLS?

Comment: well yeah you are right, what I am using is basically WLS. I premultiply my data by the weight matrix and then run it through OLS, which just gets me the WLS estimates.

The problem still remains, how do I estimate sigma^2 correctly?